# French characters not displaying correctly in PHP mail

Tags: email, utf-8, character-encoding, php

I have a basic PHP mail form, but whatever I do, I cannot seem to get the characters to display correctly once sent, if the language is written with French accents.

The example sentence I am using is:

> Bonjour, ceci est un message de test envoyé avec PHP pour analyser si
>   oui ou non la mise en forme est correcte ou fausse. Les personnages ne
>   devraient être rendus de manière appropriée comme prévu dans le
>   lexique français.

But it comes out as:

> Bonjour, ceci est un message de test envoyÃ© avec PHP pour analyser si
>   oui ou non la mise en forme est correcte ou fausse. Les personnages ne
>   devraient Ãªtre rendus de maniÃ¨re appropriÃ©e comme prÃ©vu dans le
>   lexique franÃ§ais.

As you can see, the characters with accents are screwed up, once they are received in the email.

I am processing my message variable as such:

```
$fieldenquiry = utf8_encode($_POST['fieldenquiry']);
```

I am then, sending it like so:

```
$cc = "example@example.com";
$subject = "Website Enquiry";

$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= "<p><strong>Enquiry</strong><br />" . nl2br($fieldenquiry) . "</p>";
$message .= "</body></html>";

$headers = "From: " . $fieldemail . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Cc: " . $cc . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". $fieldemail . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

I'm not a PHP developer by any means. The form works in the sense that it sends etc, but I cannot figure out why the characters mess up. I am encoding the POST variable and I am sending the HTML format with a UTF-8 charset.

Help and guidance appreciated.

Michael.

**EDIT:**

I figured this out. See my answer below.

Comment: Can you please check your encoding on your PHP file ? Is it UTF-8 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out if anyone is in need of a similar piece of help:

I changed this line:

```
$fieldenquiry = utf8_encode($_POST['fieldenquiry']);
```

To this:

```
$fieldenquiry = utf8_encode(htmlentities($_POST['fieldenquiry'], ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
```

I use the htmlentities() function with UTF-8 specified in the arguments.

This fixed the issue completely. Hope it helps someone.