# Mail sender name not displayed properly for French character

Tags: php, email, opencart

I use opencart OC2 open source ecommerce software. When an order has been placed, the merchant receives an order confirmation by mail (as coded in catalog_model_checkout_order.php).
I have modified the setSender as following in order to display the name of the buyer in my mailbox instead of the name of my shop:

Original code:

```
$mail->setSender(html_entity_decode($order_info['store_name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

Replaced code:

```
$mail->setSender(html_entity_decode($order_info['payment_firstname']." ".$order_info['payment_lastname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
```

The problem is when a buyer name with French characters appears, then these strange characters are not correctly encoded.
For instance the name "Amélie Lastname" appears as "AmÃ©lie Lastname" as sender name in my mailbox. As far as I understand, an encoding with UTF-8 is the correct and most common way?

I have already tried to use the ISO-8859-15 encoding without success (same problem:
Trial ISO-8859-15 encoding:

```
$mail->setSender(html_entity_decode($order_info['payment_firstname']." ".$order_info['payment_lastname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-15'));
```

The mail is send using the following classical mailing protocol:

```
$mail = new Mail();
$mail->protocol = $this->config->get('config_mail_protocol');
$mail->parameter = $this->config->get('config_mail_parameter');
$mail->smtp_hostname = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_hostname');
$mail->smtp_username = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_username');
$mail->smtp_password = html_entity_decode($this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_password'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$mail->smtp_port = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_port');
$mail->smtp_timeout = $this->config->get('config_mail_smtp_timeout');
$mail->setTo($this->config->get('config_email'));
$mail->setFrom($order_info['email']);
$mail->setSender(html_entity_decode($order_info['payment_firstname']." ".$order_info['payment_lastname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
$mail->setSubject(html_entity_decode($subject, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));
$mail->setHtml($html);
$mail->setText($text);
$mail->send();
```

Are there any suggestions to get the french characters correctly displayed in the sender column of my mailbox.

Thanks for any help.
SabKo

Comment: Does this help? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802692/french-characters-not-displaying-correctly-in-php-mail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12802692/french-characters-not-displaying-correctly-in-php-mail)

Comment: Hello Yunath, if I understand correctly I should change the setsender code and add a htmlentities function like below : $mail->setSender(html_entity_decode(htmlentities($order_info['payment_firstname']." ".$order_info['payment_lastname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')));

Comment: Unfortunately the suggestion $mail->setSender(html_entity_decode(htmlentities($order_info‌​['payment_firstname'‌​]." ".$order_info['payment_lastname'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'))); does not work. Any other suggestions?